# Download source Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 and later

Tags: macos, mac, data-transfer

I need download source Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 (and later) to create USB and boost it.

But I can't find the way download it.

With Yosemite 10.10, I download from the following link:
https://thepiratebay.am/torrent/11231245/OS_X_Yosemite_10.10

Comment: Do not download any sort of installer or application from torrents. Doing so will eventually make your computer into a part of botnet (known as a zombie) if you're not lucky. I would strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you download and install Yosemite previously? It should be still available for download when you will open Apple Store. In terms of specific branch (10.10.X), you can always download 10.10 and then once the Yosemite is installed, perform an update to apply Hotfixes to the recent 10.10.X version.